# Make Spring Data automatic DataSource dependent on Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Bean that fetches database credentials from an external source, and sets them as system properties. I want to ensure the DataSource automatically configured by Spring Data depends on my Bean, so I can ensure that the credentials have been fetched and set before the DataSource Bean is created.

Is there a way to do this without implementing a DataSource bean myself with the `DependsOn` annotation?

Comment: You should provide to Spring Context your own DataSource bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be potential solution for your reference , you can make use of spring `@Configuration` and  `@AutoConfigureBefore`
the code snippet like following

```
@AutoConfiguration(before = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.class }) 
// above is AutoConfiguration is dataSource Autowired , such as mysql oracle ,and some else
public class CustomDataSourceAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
     public CustomCredentials customCredentials(){
         // get your external source credentials
     }

}
```

for more annotation, you can read the spring source code , tht package path is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition`